# Best way to convert html entities to html characters

Tags: php, html-entities

What I need to do is convert any html entities to the actual html character. It can be in javascript or preferable php.

Here's the senario. When I save content to the database from TinyMCE it converts it to html entities for me. That's all good and great when the webpage is rendered, but when I also what to put it in a text input the html entities stick and to a normal user it looks a little wonky.

The only way I can think of doing it is have an array with the entity as the key and character as the value. When an entity is found, check that array and spit out the value.

Does anyone have a better/more efficient solution, possibly using regex?

Comment: read `htmlentities()`, `htmlspecialchar()`..everything is there in php manual...ALL D BEST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[html_entity_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) sounds like it is what you are after. It isn't often that people want to take HTML input from users and then display it as text later though.

Comment: Yeah I realize its not an everyday thing and it was inconsistent in my script. Just figured out a more consistent way of doing achieving what I need but thanks for the answer because I'm sure it will come up again in the furtue. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can obviously use `html_entity_decode` at the PHP level or if you're getting the data to javascript through ajax you can use `unescape()` javascript function to do the same thing at the client-side

Comment: `unescape` deals with hex encoding, not html encoding and is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions

Answer (score 2):

Use php function `html_entity_decode`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried applying `html_entity_decode` to your text? [Documentation here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)